# finding bounds of parametric variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

Compute the area of the surface $$x^2+y^2-z^2=2y+2z$$ where $-1\leq z \leq 0$

You can get it in the form $x^2+(y-1)^2=(z+1)^2$

I parametrised it as $r(u,v)=(u\cos v, u\sin v+1, u-1)$.

I know that the surface is like a cut version of a cone. But how do I find the limits of $u$ and $v$ so I can do the double integral to find surface area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compute following Jacobi Matrix: $J_{ij} = \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial w_j}$. Here $x_1=x,x_2=y,x_3=z,w_1=u,w_2=v$. Defining the $2 \times 2$-Matrix $g_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^3 J_{ki}J_{kj} = (J^TJ)_{ij}$ you can compute the following Surface integral:

$S = \int_{u_{min}}^{u_{max}}\int_{v_{min}}^{v_{max}} \sqrt{det(g)}dv du$. Since $v$ is an angle variable it holds $v_{min}=0,v_{max}= 2 \pi$. Moreover $u_{min}=0,u_{max}=1$ because $u=z+1$ (in your $z$-component of $r(u,v)$ was a small mistake; it must be $(r(u,v))_z=u-1$) and $-1 \leq z \leq 0$.

Comment: how is u=z+1? isn't it u=z-1

Comment: If $x = ucos v,y = u sin v + 1$ then $x^2+(y-1)^2=u^2cos^2v+u^2sin^2v=u^2=(z+1)^2$. This is only true if $z = u-1$.

Comment: oh yeah sorry...

Comment: I can see how you simply got the bounds for $u$ but not $v$. So if it is always an angle variable, it is always 0 to 2pi?

Comment: to cover all values of $x$ and $y$ on the given Surface it must be integrated over all angles from $0$ to $2 \pi$.